# How do I correct this Illegal String Offset?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am receiving this error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/evento/lib/php/extra.class.php on line 32"

and I realized this section of code in the file is wrong, however I'm not that great in PHP yet and I am wondering if someone can help me re-write this section to eliminate the error. Thanks! (the error starts on line 32 which is the beginning of the if statement below)

Here is the code:

```
/* new version */
    function get_attachment_struct( $inputs ){
        $attach = array();

    if( $inputs['type'] == 'attach' ){ 
            $name = $inputs['name'];
            $attach = array(
                0 => array(
                    'name' => $name,
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' =>  'Attachment URL',
                    'lvisible' => false,
                    'upload' => true,
                ),
                1 => array(
                    'name' => $name .'_id',
                    'type' => 'hidden',
                    'upload' => true
                ),
            );

            if( isset( $inputs[ 'classes' ] ) ){
                $attach[0]['classes'] = $inputs[ 'classes' ];
                $attach[1]['classes'] = $inputs[ 'classes' ] . '_id';
            }
        }
        return $attach;
    }

    /* new version */
```

Comment: Your $inputs is probably not an array or doesn't have the 'type' offset. Try doing var_dump() or print_r() on the argument before using it with the function. The code seem's ok at first glance Edit: On your $attach => 0 array, after 'upload' => true you should take out that comma.

Comment: @aleation I would say it might be better to add a comma to the second array than remove one from the first, but it is not an error in either case.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
if ($inputs['type'] == 'attach') {
```

The code is valid, but it expects the function parameter `$inputs` to be an array. The "Illegal string offset" warning when using `$inputs['type']` means that the function is being passed a string instead of an array. (And then since a string offset is a number, `'type'` is not suitable.)

So in theory the problem lies elsewhere, with the caller of the code not providing a correct parameter.

However, this warning message is new to PHP 5.4. Old versions didn't warn if this happened. They would silently convert `'type'` to `0`, then try to get character 0 (the first character) of the string. So if this code was supposed to work, that's because abusing a string like this didn't cause any complaints on PHP 5.3 and below. (A lot of old PHP code has experienced this problem after upgrading.)

You might want to debug *why* the function is being given a string by examining the calling code, and find out what value it has by doing a `var_dump($inputs);` in the function. But if you just want to shut the warning up to make it behave like PHP 5.3, change the line to:

```
if (is_array($inputs) && $inputs['type'] == 'attach') {
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes - this is related to upgrading to PHP 5.4 which so far has been a giant pain. I'm switching themes in the near future and I don't want to deal with re-writing it properly or digging into what it was, so thank you so much for giving me an easy work around. Thats more PHP than I know at the moment. Thank you!

Comment: thanks so much! for those coming after / searchers: this fixed my problem with the megusta theme - guess my host upgraded php :/

Comment: In addition to @Boann you should find out where the string comes from.
To do this you could put this code after `function get_attachment_struct( $inputs ){`:
`if(!is_array($inputs)){
var_dump(debug_backtrace);
}`

If you don't want to see the output on the frontpage you could also log it into a text file. Simply change `var_dump(debug_backtrace);` to `file_put_contents('debug.txt',var_export(debug_backtrace(),true).PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);`
Therefore the log is store in debug.txt (or the filename you provide).
But be aware that logging may consume many storage capacity.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($rule["type"]) && ($rule["type"] == "radio") || ($rule["type"] == "checkbox") )
{
    if(!isset($data[$field]))
        $data[$field]="";
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate the OP and future readers.  Always endeavor to explain, to some degree, what your method does and why it is an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($inputs['type']) && $inputs['type'] == 'attach') {
```

or

```
if (is_array($inputs) && isset($inputs['type']) && $inputs['type'] == 'attach') {
```

Comment: `isset($inputs['type'])` will guarantee that `$inputs` is an array -- the `is_array()` check can be safely removed.

Answer (score -3):

I get the same error in WP when I use php ver 7.1.6 - just take your php version back to 7.0.20 and the error will disappear.

Comment: Because downgrading the php version is always a scalable solution

Comment: This is a ridiculous answer.