# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what may be happening with some PHP errors. They read like this:

> "Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in /home/awh/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/shortcodes.php on line 440"

The 'guilty lines' are 440,445,448,453, I've marked the lines in the code below (hope that's ok?)

The website is www.advancewithhealth.com and the errors seem to be generated due to some errors in the slider PHP code (it's a family friend so I'm not sure what changes she may have accidentally). I've included the guilty lines below:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Slide
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
add_shortcode('slide', 'shortcode_slide');
function shortcode_slide($atts, $content = null) {
    $str = '';
    if($atts['type'] == 'video') { // <-- 440
        $str .= '<li class="video">';
    } else {
        $str .= '<li class="image">';
    }
    if($atts['link']): // <-- 445
    $str .= '<a href="'.$atts['link'].'">';
    endif;
    if($atts['type'] == 'video') { // <-- 448
        $str .= $content;
    } else {
        $str .= '<img src="'.$content.'" alt="" />';
    }
    if($atts['link']): // <-- 453
    $str .= '</a>';
    endif;
    $str .= '</li>';

    return $str;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Warmly,
Carlo

Comment: You're probably passing a string instead of an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I correct this Illegal String Offset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361392/how-do-i-correct-this-illegal-string-offset)

Comment: The code that's calling this function seems to be passing a string instead of an array. You'd need to look there.

Comment: @MikeW I'm not even seeing a call to `shortcode_slide` in this entire script. I see a call `add_shortcode`. Did I miss the function call or is the OP's script incomplete?

Comment: thanks guys. i saw a few similar threads but because of my limited php knowledge it didn't really help. sorry if it's a duplicate, should i delete my post?

Comment: @War10ck The OP has posted only the function that the errors are appearing in. Looking at the line numbers there's 400+ lines of code before this that we're not seeing.

Comment: @CarloDelFabbro The linked duplicate covers similar ground but the accepted solution relates to a migration from PHP5.3 to PHP5.4. If that covers your situation then it's a duplicate and you can delete it. If not, the problem is elsewhere in your code. We can't diagnose it from what you've posted.

Comment: There are no default attribute values set, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because you are not passing in the `type` attribute to your arguments for the shortcode. You can avoid the error by using:

```
[slide type='video'/]
```

That said, the [correct way to account for this programmatically and reliably](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes) is to use [`shortcode_atts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) function to set default values on your `$atts` array.

```
// the default $atts values
$defaults = array( 'type' => 'default value' );

// use array merge to override values in $defaults with those in $atts
$atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts );

// now the index will be set even if it wasn't passed into the shortcode
if( $atts['type'] == 'video' ) {
```

If you don't want to set any default values (even though you could default to `false` or something), you can also just check that the index is set on the array before accessing using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). I would recommend using the method above.

```
if( isset( $atts['type'] ) && $atts['type'] == 'video' ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into the same issue and I solved it by changing the code calling the slider similar to:

```
[slider][slide link=""]image link[/slide][slide link=""]image link here[/slide][/slider]
```

In my case the `link=""` was missing.