# Illegal string offset 'name', code worked with example json response

Tags: php, json, api

I'm currently working on a website to control my SmartBulbs at home via a webpage. To do so I use the provided API.

I tried my code with an example json response from the manufacturers website. Everything worked fine and all the lights listed in the example response where represented by divs with the names of the lights.

When I tried my code at home (called the API like in the code) I got a valid response but I also got an error which stated *Illegal string offset 'label'*. What am I doing wrong?

Everything worked fine when I used the example response. The response when I use the API looks the same for me. Shouldn't it also work then?

You can find everything down below. If you need some mor information just ask :)

**php code**

```
function get_lights(){

    $link = "https://api.lifx.com/v1/lights/all";
    $authToken = "I inserted my token here and got a valid response";

    $ch = curl_init($link);
    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $authToken);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $json = json_decode($response, true);

    $html = null;
    foreach($json as $object)
        {
        $html.= '<div class="element" onclick="get_info();">' . $object['label'] . '</div>';
        }

    return $html;

    }
```

**example response**

```
[
  {
    "id": "d3b2f2d97452",
    "uuid": "8fa5f072-af97-44ed-ae54-e70fd7bd9d20",
    "label": "Left Lamp",
    "connected": true,
    "power": "on",
    "color": {
      "hue": 250.0,
      "saturation": 0.5,
      "kelvin": 3500
    },
    "infrared": "1.0",
    "brightness": 0.5,
    "group": {
      "id": "1c8de82b81f445e7cfaafae49b259c71",
      "name": "Lounge"
    },
    "location": {
      "id": "1d6fe8ef0fde4c6d77b0012dc736662c",
      "name": "Home"
    },
    "last_seen": "2015-03-02T08:53:02.867+00:00",
    "seconds_since_seen": 0.002869418,
    "product": {
      "name": "LIFX+ A19",
      "company": "LIFX",
      "identifier": "lifx_plus_a19",
      "capabilities": {
        "has_color": true,
        "has_variable_color_temp": true,
        "has_ir": true,
        "has_multizone": false
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**my API response**

```
  [  
   {  
      "id":"d073d513bfd6",
      "uuid":"02ea5835-9dc2-4323-84f3-3b825419008d",
      "label":"MainLight",
      "connected":true,
      "power":"on",
      "color":{  
         "hue":27.581597619592586,
         "saturation":0.0,
         "kelvin":2500
      },
      "zones":null,
      "brightness":0.49999237048905165,
      "group":{  
         "id":"d5aa0e1180293e0af56607cbe47f4940",
         "name":"MyRoom"
      },
      "location":{  
         "id":"451e4b376a38062cdd10c54ab2698975",
         "name":"My Home"
      },
      "product":{  
         "name":"Color 1000",
         "identifier":"lifx_color_a19",
         "company":"LIFX",
         "capabilities":{  
            "has_color":true,
            "has_variable_color_temp":true,
            "has_ir":false,
            "has_multizone":false
         }
      },
      "infrared":null,
      "last_seen":"2017-02-18T21:40:58.164+00:00",
      "seconds_since_seen":0.001675218
   }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correct this Illegal String Offset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361392/how-do-i-correct-this-illegal-string-offset)  (and if not, then just do a search for "illegal string offset").  Also see [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is no mention of "name" in your code. That code will not produce the error you're reporting.

Comment: @miken32 Sorry, I corrected my question now. I have to functions, one is listing the lights, the other one my scenes. Both report the same error (except scenes have names instead of labels). I simply copied the wrong one.

Comment: Try `var_dump($response)` and make sure that JSON is really what you're getting. I suggest you're getting a string value back and not an object.

Comment: @miken32 Ok, I tried it again with var_dump. I got the following: array(1) { ["error"]=> string(14) "Token required" }. However, I don't know what it means and I can't find any results for it on google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the wrong option for your cURL handle:

```
$ch = curl_init($link);
$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $authToken);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Replacing the the option didn't solve my problem, however, adding it did.I now have to curl_setopt-functions. At this point I don't know why it's working. I would be happy if you could explain why it only works with both curl_opt- functions together :)

Comment: Yes, if you need both options set you'll need to call the function twice, or use `curl_setopt_array()`.  One sets the header, one indicates that you want `curl_exec()` to return the transferred data.