# Warning: Illegal string offset while searching of product

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am working on a woocomerce wordpress website.

So I am trying to search for a product in search bar it is giving me this error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'LargeImage' in /home3/curtis22/public_html/shopnowshoplater.com/wp-content/themes/shopnowshoplater/search.php on line 31

Warning: Illegal string offset 'URL' in /home3/curtis22/public_html/shopnowshoplater.com/wp-content/themes/shopnowshoplater/search.php on line 31

Warning: Illegal string offset 'LargeImage' in /home3/curtis22/public_html/shopnowshoplater.com/wp-content/themes/shopnowshoplater/search.php on line 31

Warning: Illegal string offset 'URL' in /home3/curtis22/public_html/shopnowshoplater.com/wp-content/themes/shopnowshoplater/search.php on line 31

Warning: Illegal string offset 'LargeImage' in /home3/curtis22/public_html/shopnowshoplater.com/wp-content/themes/shopnowshoplater/search.php on line 31

Warning: Illegal string offset 'URL' in /home3/curtis22/public_html/shopnowshoplater.com/wp-content/themes/shopnowshoplater/search.php on line 31
```

This is the product I am searching for: "westinghouse igen2500 portable inverter generator"

```js
$id = get_the_ID();
$array = $_GET;
$key = array_keys($array);
$cat = $key[0];

$page_n = $key[2];
$keyword = $array[$cat];
$searchkeyword = $array['s'];

$row = 1;
if (isset($page_n)) {
    $row = $array[$page_n];
}

$data = get_category_products($keyword, $searchkeyword, $row);
//print_r($data); exit;
$itemPerPage = 10;
$totalItems = $data['totalItems'];
$totalPages = $data['totalPages'];

$items = $data['items'];
foreach ($items as $item) {
 $image = $item['LargeImage']['URL'];
 
 if( (!isset($image)) && $image=='' ){
  unset($item);
 }
}
$page_url = '';
get_header();
$page_urlbrd = $page_url;
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correct this Illegal String Offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361392/how-do-i-correct-this-illegal-string-offset)

Comment: Yes,when i put a product in a search it shows me above errors

Comment: I think the accepted answer on that other question will give you a place to start. `$item` needs to be an array, and it appears not to be. Work backwards from there.