# How to fix Illegal string offset in php

Tags: php, html

I'm working on my web application, so I have to collect some questions from users to put that in my database, but I'm getting this error

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminarskirad
>   - Copy\kontaktKlasa.php on line 138

```
public function set_message($message,$type) {        
     $this->poruka['msg'] = $message;        
     $this->poruka['type'] = $type;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correct this Illegal String Offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361392/how-do-i-correct-this-illegal-string-offset)

Comment: The error means that `$this->poruka` is a string, not an array.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without seeing the rest of the class. Either you're trying to put into the wrong variable, or you have some code that's replacing the array with a string when it shouldn't. Or maybe you're just not initializing `$this->poruka` correctly.